# passing UTF8 string to external command from REXX

Tags: utf-8, rexx

I need to access some files with russian filenames from REXX.

The filenames are listed in a text file.

The code correctly reads the input list of filenames, but when the code invokes an external command using as a parameter the line that has been read, it fails.

The simplified code is

```
 say "SRC" FQO ;
 say "DEST" FQD ;
 say "CHCP" 
 CHCP
 newCMD = 'XCOPY /Y' FQO FQD
 say "CMD" newCMD ;
 newCMD
```

And the displayed result is

```
 SRC C:\prive\$_Родословная.txt
 DEST C:\data\ 
 CHCP
 Active code page: 65001
 CMD XCOPY /Y C:\prive\$_Родословная.txt C:\data\ 
 File not found - $_Ð Ð¾Ð´Ð¾ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ð°Ñ.txt
 0 File(s) copied
```

It seems as if the Rexx Interpreter did not honor the current codepage (65001) for invoking the external NewCMD.

Any clues ?

Comment: Which platform, which Rexx ????. I do not know the answer, but This will help others

Comment: Windows Open Object Rexx 4.1